# Oracle - DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS get's different results (owners) from script and procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

on one of my servers i detect weird behaviour:

I have table TEST_OWNERS(owner varchar2(100)

When I execute this statement:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_OWNERS
select distinct owner from DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS;
commit;
```

I have all owners in the table.
But, when I try to create procedure with the same statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_OWNERS_P IS
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE('TRUNCATE TABLE TEST_OWNERS');
INSERT INTO TEST_OWNERS
select distinct owner from DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS;
commit;
END;
```

And execute it from the same window, the same session - I can see only user, who executed procedure :|

On another server evyrything is ok - script and procedure returns the same results.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The query that you are using to populate the table is dependent on the jobs that have been run in the database. If there are different jobs running in DB1 than in DB2, then your query will likely have different results.

If you are just trying to get a list of users in the database, then you can use `select username from dba_users`

Comment: Yes, jobs information is what I need - but as I wrote, executing insert from script gives me everything I need, unfortunatelly executing this in procedure (executed by the same user) filter my data only for this user - example I provided with only Owner table is just for simplify.